# Route with name "blog" not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am following https://zf2-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/in-depth-guide/data-binding.html.

I have below code:

**edit.phtml:**

```
 <h2>EDIT FORM</h2>

 <?php

  $form = $this->form;
  $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('post/edit', array('id' => $this->id), true));
  $form->prepare();
  $form->get('submit')->setValue('Update Post');

  echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

  echo $this->formCollection($form);

  echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

**WriteController.php:**(the action part)

```
  public function editAction()
  {
     $request = $this->getRequest();
     $post    = $this->postService->findPost($this->params('id'));

     $this->postForm->bind($post);

     if ($request->isPost()) {
         $this->postForm->setData($request->getPost());

         if ($this->postForm->isValid()) {
             try {
                 $this->postService->savePost($post);

                 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
             } catch (\Exception $e) {
                 die($e->getMessage());
                 // Some DB Error happened, log it and let the user know
             }
         }
     }

     return new ViewModel(array(
         'form' => $this->postForm,
         'id'=>$this->params('id')
     ));


  }
```

**module.config.php:**(route part)

```
'router'=>array(

    'routes'=>array(

        'post'=>array(

            'type'=>'literal',

            'options'=>array(

                'route'=>'/blog',
                'defaults'=>array(

                    'controller'=>'Blog\Controller\List',
                    'action'=>'index'


                )
            ),
            'may_terminate'=>true,
            'child_routes'=>array(

                'detail'=>array(
                    'type'=>'segment',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'route'=>'/:id',
                        'defaults'=>array(
                            'action'=>'detail'
                        ),
                        'constraints'=>array(
                            'id'=>'\d+'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                 'add'=>array(
                     'type'=>'literal',
                     'options'=>array(
                     'route'=>'/add',
                     'defaults'=>array(
                        'controller'=>'Blog\Controller\Write',
                        'action'=>'add'
                        )
                    )
                ),
               'edit' => array(
                     'may_terminate'=>true,
                     'type' => 'segment',
                     'options' => array(
                         'route'    => '/edit/:id',
                         'defaults' => array(
                             'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Write',
                             'action'     => 'edit'
                         ),
                         'constraints' => array(
                             'id' => '\d+'
                         )
                     )
                 ),

             )
        ),


    )
),
```

**Problem:**

When I try to get the editable form by like `http://www.myzend.com/blog/edit/2` I get the below error.

> Route with name "blog" not found

**Note:** When I put only static html in `edit.phtml`,page with static content displayed correctly.

I am using `Zend Framework 2.3.3`

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: try adding 'may_terminate'=>true,` to your child routes (and check for type-os, just in case :)).

Comment: I added 'may_terminate'=>true,` under `edit` route,not happening

Comment: if it's the same as in the code sample above then it's in the wrong place. It needs to be in the array under `edit` key -- now it's outside of it.

Comment: Code updated,I doubt it is configured correctly in `edit.phtml` as in  $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('blog/edit', array('id' => $form->id), true));

Comment: ha true, haven't noticed this: you reference `blog/edit` and your route is `post/edit`. Try that latter one in your template.

Comment: Corrected,looks like working now.

Comment: also you might want to check if the `controller` keys values match controllers in your service provider or put full class names there (unless ZF2 does that automatically now, but I wouldn't bet on it).